# modify syntax entry globally?

Tags: syntax-table

I'd like to treat underscores (`_`) as word characters everywhere (prog-mode, text, comments, etc.). I'm currently doing so in specific modes, like this:

```
(add-hook ruby-mode-hook #'ivan-treat-underscore-as-word-char)
(defun ivan-treat-underscore-as-word-char () (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w"))
```

But I'm not sure how to do the equivalent across the board. Even in ruby-mode, I find that underscores don't behave like word-characters inside strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do something in *every* mode then you can use `after-change-major-mode-hook` to run your code.

Comment: That did the trick, and solved a whole bunch of completion pain points I was having. Thank you!